# Processing command line arguments, allowing for any order

Tags: c++, command-line, user-input

Ok I am creating a program that allows user input in any order. The term -1 or -2 is used to indicate an operating mode. while the argument -c always precedes a filename. Here is the loop I have written to allow these to be entered in any order the user wishes.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string qcolors_name;
    string inputFileName;
    pmode_t mode = run_process2;
    // perform command line argument checking
    if(argc < 2){
        cerr << "Not enough arguments" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++){
        if(argv[i] == "-1"){
            mode = run_process1;
            cout << "Mode 1" << endl;
        }else if(argv[i] == "-2"){
            mode = run_process2;
        }else if(argv[i] == "-c"){
            qcolors_name = argv[i+1];
            cout << qcolors_name << endl;
            i++;
        }else if(argc-1 == i){
            break;
        }else{
            cout << argv[i] <<endl;
            cerr << "arguments error"<<endl;;
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

However the program seems to always dump out to the arguments error message even though it outputs that argv[i] is = -1. This is one of the things I have tested for though and should never have reached this case. Im sure its something syntax wise that I am doing wrong.

EDIT

Here is an imput with a sample error output.

```
USER> ./colorfun -1 -c qc_bw.txt mountains.ppm      <-  9:46PM
-1
arguments error
```

Comment: What's the exact command line that's failing?

Comment: I added an example input and the output error its currently giving me.

Comment: I do, the if argc-1 == i check ignores the last input. Sorry I ment to add that the last input is also always a filename. Its failing for the -1. As you can see from the output error since it prints the current argument right before outputting the error. Whoops, its also accounted for by the fact the loop itself doesn't check the last entry

Comment: You are comparing `char *` with `==` which is not what you really want.
You should use `strcmp` here.

Comment: Incidentally, the only thing that would produce an output of "-1" would be the block with `if (argv[i] == "-c")` if -1 was directly after -c.  Are you sure the code and the input/output match?

Comment: I would recommend that you use a library for this. Depending on your target you might find OS specific libraries, or you can use a generic solution like boost program options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's C, you can't compare strings with just str1 == "smth". Use `strcmp()` instead.

More detailed explanations: operator `==` in C compares integral entities: numbers, pointers, etc. `"smth"` is essentially a pointer to memory area in constant segment of your program. That's why code like

```
const char* a = "abc";
const char* b = "abc";
assert(a == b);
```

*may* give true, both a & b may point to a single memory location. But this expression *never* compares letters "a", "b", "c" from `a` and `b`, it compares just pointers. Likewise in Java you have to use `str1.equals(str2)` because Java operator == also compares integral entities (numbers, characters and "pointers to Objects"). In opposite in C++, Python and other programming languages with operator overloading,  `==` for two strings usually leads to character by character comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have to convert the arguments to std::string first, then you can compare them using the == operator, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-a") {
            std::cout << "You passed parameter -a" << std::endl;
        } else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-b") {
            std::cout << "You passed parameter -b" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```